# Pandas groupby sum difference shift cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table similiar to this

```
import pandas as pd
data =  [['2019-02-01',0 ,5],
 ['2019-02-01',1, 12],
 ['2019-02-01',2,18],
 ['2019-02-01' ,3, 23],
 ['2019-02-01' ,4 ,20],
 ['2019-03-01',0 ,12],
 ['2019-03-01', 1,7],
 ['2019-03-01' ,2, 6],
 ['2019-03-01' ,3, 5],
 ['2019-03-01' ,4, 8]]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start_Month', 'Bucket','Complete'])
```

I want a new column where for each start_Month it would calculate the sum difference of the shift value of complete. Like the first value will be the sum of Complete groupby start_Month Eg for 2019-02-01 is 78 while the next one i.e bucket 1 will be 78-5=8=73(the 5 is complete value for bucket 0) and for bucket 2 for the same start_month would be 78-5-12=61 like the below one with values but in the picture showing the calculations.

[image]

```
df['new_Com']=df.groupby(['Start_Month']).Complete.sum() - df.groupby(['Start_Month']).Complete.shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with reversed the order and `cumsum`

```
df['New'] = df.iloc[::-1].groupby('Start_Month').Complete.cumsum()
df
  Start_Month  Bucket  Complete  New
0  2019-02-01       0         5   78
1  2019-02-01       1        12   73
2  2019-02-01       2        18   61
3  2019-02-01       3        23   43
4  2019-02-01       4        20   20
5  2019-03-01       0        12   38
6  2019-03-01       1         7   26
7  2019-03-01       2         6   19
8  2019-03-01       3         5   13
9  2019-03-01       4         8    8
```